# Inserting into MySQL table by 'for' loop with variables between strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in a .php file. On action i send $_POST variables to another .php file, where i add the form/input results into the database table.

But there seems to be a problem at one specific place. The table is created correctly, there is connection. However, i can't insert data.

Here are my inputs from the original .php file. They generate without mistakes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="player<?php echo $i; ?>-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text" <?php if($i>5){echo "disabled ";}?> />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="player<?php echo $i; ?>-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" <?php if($i>5){echo "disabled ";}?> />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="player<?php echo $i; ?>-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" <?php if($i>5){echo "disabled ";}?> />
</div> <?php } ?>
```

in the .php file, where i send the variables, i create a table:

```
$team_name = $_POST["team"];
$query = "CREATE TABLE " . strtolower($team_name) . " (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,team_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,short_name varchar(255) NOT NULL)";
mysqli_query($_SESSION["mySqlLink"],$query);
```

There is no error here, the table is created.

The error (not inserting into the table) seems to be here:

```
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    if(!empty($_POST["player". $i ."-fn"]) && !empty($_POST["player". $i ."-ln"]) && !empty($_POST["player". $i ."-nr"])){
        $first_name = $_POST["player". $i ."-fn"];
        $last_name = $_POST["player". $i ."-ln"];
        $number = $_POST["player". $i ."-nr"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO ". $team_name ." (number,first_name,last_name) VALUES ('$number','$first_name','$last_name')";
        mysqli_query($_SESSION["mySqlLink"],$query);
    }
    else break;
}
```

I have 12 inputs but not a single one is inserted into the table. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Lukas, it was answered. We don't need a status in the title or the question.

Comment: Mark Ravi's answer with a Green Check mark under the arrows :p

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table column name (id,team_name,short_name)
You are trying to insert (number,first_name,last_name)
Insert column name should be same table column name
Code will be like below:

```
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    if(!empty($_POST["player". $i ."-fn"]) && !empty($_POST["player". $i ."-ln"]) && !empty($_POST["player". $i ."-nr"])){
        $first_name = $_POST["player". $i ."-fn"];
        $last_name = $_POST["player". $i ."-ln"];
        $number = $_POST["player". $i ."-nr"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO ". $team_name ." (id,team_name,short_name) VALUES ('$number','$first_name','$last_name')";
        mysqli_query($_SESSION["mySqlLink"],$query);
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: oh my god. such a silly mistake. thanks for your notice. i feel embaressed.